# Setting individual divs to Hide/Show when there a multiple entries from a My SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am just beginning to figure out PHP and Javascript, so forgive me if I am doing something silly with my method...

I have a PHP script that gets values from a MySQL database after a submit button has been pressed. The data goes into a template and works very well. If there are multiple entires these show below, in there own individual templates'.

However the template has a section at the bottom that is hidden and is revealed when a button is clicked. The hide/show works if one result displays, however **if multiple results from the database load, and the button on the first option is clicked then it opens all the other options hide/show too!** Not just on the one template that has been clicked.

I have thought of a solution where I add the row `id` to the template containers `id`. i.e

`<div class="template-container" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">`.

Then I am using this JS to hide and show the reveal part of the template:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

            $(".reveal-container").hide();
            $("#reveal-arrow").click(function(){
            $(".reveal-container").slideToggle();
            $("#reveal-arrow").toggleClass('flip');
    });
});
    </script>
```

I have been trying to add  like:

```
$("#<?php echo $row['id'];?> .reveal-container").hide();
```

By referring to the `id` I thought it may work....But its not!

How is the best way to have each individual hide/show when the button in its respective template is clicked.

I have looked around and also found using $(this) may help... however I can't figure out how!

Thanks in advance!

Update- Here is HTML:

```
<div class="template-container" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" >
    <img id="est_img" src="assets/Restaurants.png">
    <div id="address_subtitle"><?php echo $row['locale'];?>, London</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">

    <div id="est_title"><?php echo $row['name'];?> <b>9/2</b></div>
    <div id="know_subtitle">Know For: <b>NONE</b></div>
      <div id="price_subtitle"> <?php echo $row['price_range'];?> </div>
      <div id="tags_subtitle">PLACEHOLDER</div>
      <img id="reveal-arrow" src="assets/Arrow-Down-icon.png">
  </div>

</div>
    <div class="solid-line"></div>
    <div class="reveal-container">

        <div class="button-row">

            <button id="visited_button">Visited</button><button     id="add_list_button">Add To List</button>

        </div>

        <div class="info-row">

            <div id="full_address_subtitle">PLACEHOLDER</div>
            <div class="grey-line"></div>
            <div id="telephone_subtitle"><a href="tel:<?php echo $row['phone_number'];?>"><?php echo $row['phone_number'];?></a></div> 
            <div id="website_subtitle"><a href="<?php echo $row['website'];?>" target="_blank" >Visit Website</a></div>

        <div class="comments-row">

        </div>




    </div>

</div></div>


    <?php }}} ?>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){  

            $(".reveal-container").hide();
            $("#reveal-arrow").click(function(){
            $(".reveal-container").slideToggle();
            $("#reveal-arrow").toggleClass('flip');
    });
});
    </script>


    <form method="post">
    Club: <input type='checkbox' name="selectClub" value="1" />
    Restaurant: <input type='checkbox' name="selectRestaurant" value="1" />
    Bar: <input type='checkbox' name="selectBar" value="1"/>
    Pub: <input type='checkbox' name="selectPub" value="1"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post more of the HTML?

Comment: @jwebb Just added it - Thanks!

Comment: Are all of the elements inside each <div class="template-container" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"> the same?

Comment: if the template container repeats itself, you'd have several elements with the same id's, just like with your approach of adding the row nbr as an id. this shouldn't happen. though most things work in browsers, id's are supposed to be unique over the whole document!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your final HTML looks like, but it appears your elements are repeated inside each `<div class="template-container" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">` which results in several non-unique IDs.

First of all, the ID value must be unique within the HTML document https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp. I would suggest using your PHP to make the element IDs all unique with each row. Even just a simple '-' + the loop index should be enough. Or don't use IDs where you don't need them but use classes instead.

Second of all, $("#reveal-arrow") is a jQuery ID selector and like I said, you are making rows full of elements with non-unique IDs. This means your click event is only being attached to the first one. You could make reveal-arrow a class instead of an ID.

```
$(".reveal-arrow").click(function () {
            $(".reveal-container").slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('flip');
        });
```

but then you still need to adjust the script to target THAT reveal container.

```
$(".reveal-arrow").click(function(){
              $(this).parents('.template-container').find('.reveal-container').slideToggle();
              $(this).toggleClass('flip');
 });
```

One more thing, you don't need to have `$(".reveal-container").hide();` You can just set the reveal-container to `style="display:none;"` with CSS when the page loads because slideToggle will reveal it if it's hidden. http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ Doing it that way is slightly more performant.

Comment: nice explanation. and addressed all code issues, with id's - this one should get the green checkmark!

Comment: Thanks for the help - For some reason this code doesn't work for me at all! Not sure exactly why...However @errands code below works on the first option, but none of the others. When I add console.log(clickedContainer) to check if I am getting a click, on any option except the first one I see nothing! Any idea why?

Comment: Did you change reveal-arrow to a class in the HTML or is it still an ID? class="reveal-arrow" not id="reveal-arrow" Read through the full answer, don't just copy and paste

Comment: @jwebb My apologies - I had to delete the cache in chrome then it worked! Thanks for your help and the clear explanation.

Comment: Ah yes the cache will get you sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

us the `this` selector to choose only the needed element. since your reveal arrow is somewhere 'hidden' in your container, you have to add some tree traversal to your js function:

```
$("#reveal-arrow").click(function(){
    var clickedContainer = $(this).parents(".template-container"); //go up to your parent container
    clickedContainer.find(".reveal-container").slideToggle(); //find the reveal-container child and slide toggle it
    $(this).toggleClass('flip'); // don't forget to flip your arrow
});
```